# nextSyncToken is always the same as passed in syncToken

Tags: google-people-api

I'm using the new'ish People API to track a users contacts. I request a syncToken when listing a users contacts using people.connections.list and pass this along on subsequent requests to only get changes.

If there is a change I get only the changed Person as expected. However, nextSyncToken is always the same as the syncToken I passed in. I was expecting a new sync token after a change. The documentation isn't really clear on whats supposed to happen. Anyone have any insights?

This happens with both the Golang bindings (which aren't documented on the site but work great otherwise) and when using the API explorer on - https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list

Comment: I am unable to repro. The sync token doesn't change if no changes happen. But once a contact is edited, the sync token changes for me.

Comment: You're totally correct. When eyeballing it the tokens look just similar enough that I didn't pick up the change. My bad.